# change text in facebook like button

Tags: javascript, facebook

Is there any possibility to change the text in facebook like button? For example i have to change the text `people like this` in the following button.

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: I would think that the text is based on the browser's language settings and or the user's facebook language preference if logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, No. That is served by Facebook themselves. You could place an image on top of it, though.